# Encode the string using encodeURIComponent is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encode

I am trying to encode the string using encodeURIComponent() but unable to do in React showing error.

I have refer the URL (https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) and here my string encode is working fine and I tried console also working fine but when I trying in React js showing error(Octal numeric literals and escape characters not allowed in strict mode).

Below is my string ("C:\Users\1234\test_&_est\456456_45").

I have tried with the below URL code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ttg96j

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> Octal numeric literals and escape characters not allowed in strict mode

You've to escape backslashes in your string, like this: "C:\\Users\\1234\\test_&_est\\456456_45"

Check this MDN reference for more information: [MDN Reference for strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 0):

Osama is correct, as the error explains, you need to escape your slashes.

Alternatively, as of ES2015, you can use template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

With template literals you can simply change your quote characters to ` on line 15 in your StackBlitz example:

```js
let strURL = "C:\Users\1234\test_&_est\456456_45";
```

to

```js
let strURL = `C:\Users\1234\test_&_est\456456_45`;
```

Comment: it's working but as expected output not coming. For example for \ (%5c is not coming). can you help me

Comment: As I mentioned url (https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) output is coming \ as %5c, but when I tried in react is not coming

Comment: Have a look here: [stackblitz reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nkkuej?file=index.js)
This shows that backslash is encoded to %5c

Comment: It is perfect but my input is with single slash (C:\Users\1234\test_&_est\456456_45), or is there any possibility to add one more slash for the string?

Comment: Once the input as (C:\Users\1234\test_&_est\456456_45) and out put is (C%3A%5CUsers%5C1234%5Ctest_%26_est%5C456456_45), i will mark as answer